# Gracefully close a process which has no window

Tags: c#, process, .net-4.0

I have a program that starts a specific browser in the background to run javascript unit tests.

When the tests are finished, the browser should send the results back to my program.

Finally my browser should close the browser gracefully.

My problem is that i can't use the method `Process.CloseMainWindow()` since the browser is running in the background and has no window.

I also don't want to use `Process.Kill()` because the browser could recover data at the next start.

Is there any possibility to shut down the browser carefully?

Comment: How does that process normally exit with code 0? I mean, if you run it via shell, what do you have to do for it to exit?

Comment: You know more than us about this process. Perhaps you can tell us more about it so that we have a better chance of giving you good advice.

Comment: My program starts a specific browser which should run unit tests. When the tests are finished the results should be sent back to my program. Finally my program should close the browser.

Comment: @Johny So the process you want to kill is the browser? But you said the process has no window.

Comment: Still we don't know anything actionable about this program that you want to kill.

Comment: @dcastro Yes but it's running in the background and i don't want to kill the process at the end since the browser could recover data at the next start

Comment: I rewrote my question. I hope you can understand my problem better now.

Comment: @Johny until a proper solution shows up, do you want to consider opening incognito browser windows? Killing won't cause a problem.

Comment: Well that's an idea. If there's no better solution i would do that. Thanks!